# jQuery-Mobile: repeat calls on submit form

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have two pages in different files A.html & B.html,
A is a listview, B is a form.

On page A, I click one item, then change to page B,

on page B, I submit a form by AJAX, and use ALERT(data) to show result.

I click BACK button return to A.

Question is,

1st round: click submit, alert one time,

2nd round: click submit, alert two times,

3rd round: click submit, alert three times....

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute click event of button like this:

```
$("#btn_id").on("click", function(event){
   if(event.handled !== true)
   {
      // Your code
      event.handled = true;
   }
   return false;
});
```